# Automation Process in SP 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath, rest, excel

I am creating an InfoPath form for a SharePoint list. The objective I want to achieve through automation is that

1. whenever a user submits a list item, the item should be copied to an excel sheet which is stored in the document library.
2. this excel file should be able to update the information directly to HP ALM through their add-on in Excel.

I have a feeling that (1) may be achieved through a workflow; can you please guide me through this? or give me some starting points.. For (2) can I ask if there is a way to include and automate an add on within the sharepoint-excel?

If the use of REST services is required, can please point me to a direction I can follow since I am fairly new to SP.

Thank you so much! Appreciate your help.